# fsync's performance got mix result on Linux 2.6.32 ext2 filesystem

Tags: linux, performance, ext2, fsync

While I was testing performance of fsync on my Linux machine, I found fsync costs outstanding time when inserting data into a file which grows the file, but it performs 100 times faster when inserting data that just overrides exsting content and not grows the file's size.

Env:
2-CPU with 12 cores
Linux version 2.6.32_1-14-0-0 (scmpf@pwd) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Mar 31 10:42:09 CST 2014
ext2 filesystem

Test code:

```
static int _openfile_w(char *file, bool is_sync)
{
    int flag = O_CREAT|O_RDWR;
    if (is_sync)
    {
     flag |= O_SYNC;
    }
    return open(file,flag,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
}

int test_fsync(void)
{
   #define NUMOFFSYNC 1000
   int fd = 0;
   char * filename = "/home/zhangguangzhou/tmp/0";

   fd = _openfile_w(filenames, false);
   if (fd <= 0)
   {
     UB_LOG_WARNING("%s open index file %s error",__FUNCTION__, filename);
     return -1;
   }

   char data[1024];
   memset((void*)data, 'c', sizeof(data));
   for( int i = 0; i < NUMOFFSYNC; i++)
   {
      if (lseek(fd, i*sizeof(data), SEEK_SET) < 0)
      {
          UB_LOG_WARNING("%s lseek index error, transid:curidx:%d",
          __FUNCTION__, i);
          return -1;
      }

      if (write(fd, data, sizeof(data)) != sizeof(data))
      {
          UB_LOG_WARNING("%s write index error, transid:curidx:%d",
         __FUNCTION__, i);
         return -1;
      }

      if (fsync(fd) < 0)
      {
          UB_LOG_WARNING("%s fsync error, cur_datano:%d",
          __FUNCTION__, i);
          return -1;
       }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

Running the above test_fsync program after an "echo "" >/home/zhangguangzhou/tmp/0", which vacuums the file, each fsync will cost 8ms on avg.. But when running it repeatedly, it will cost 50 us on avg. in the second and later run. While I tested insertint data from middle of the file or insert with a different size of data, the result is almost unchanged.

Question:
**What cost the extra time of fsync if the write is growing the file?**

I thought about the inode IO in fysnc, but the inode IO is the same for both file-growing write and no-file-growing write, since both of them need to update the inode metadata of file modication time.